# communication flow between fragments and activity

Tags: android, android-fragments

I'm trying to make a simple reminder app. When creating a new reminder I have the following setup:

1. *MainEditActivity.java*: 2 placeholder FrameLayouts for the following fragments:

   - *EditNameFragment.java*

     - custom Action  Bar (Cancel, OK button)
     - EditText for the reminder name
     - CheckBox to toggle one of the following fragments
   - *EditDateFragment.java* **OR** *EditLocationFragment.java* (both have a lot of views)

***MainEditActivity.java:***

```
    private LocationFragment mLocationFragment;
    private DateFragment mDateFragment;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

          setContentView(R.layout.activity_new_remainer_main); // 2 frame layouts
          if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            Fragment newFragment = new NewReminderFragment();
            FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            ft.add(R.id.reminder_title_fragment, newFragment).commit();

            mDateFragment = new DateFragment();
            ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            ft.add(R.id.date_or_location_fragment, mDateFragment).commit();
         }
    }

    public void onCheckBoxClick(View view) 
    {
       FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
       FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();   
       if(mLocationFragment == null)
         mLocationFragment = new LocationFragment();

       CheckBox checkBox = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.checkBoxID);
       if(checkBox != null)
       {
         if(checkBox.isChecked()) {
           fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.date_or_location_fragment, mLocationFragment);
        } else {
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.date_or_location_fragment, mDateFragment);
        }
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
    }

    @Override
    public void handleEvent(EventInfo event) {
          // here I get all the data (name, data, time, location, etc)
    }
```

***EditNameFragment.java:***

```
    private EventHandler mEventHandler;

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
         super.onAttach(activity);
         mEventHandler = (EventHandler)activity;
    }

    View doneButton = actionBarButtons.findViewById(R.id.doneBtnTextID);
    doneButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {      
       @Override
       public void onClick(View v) {
            createNewReminder();            
       }
    });

    private void createNewReminder()
    {
        // Event info object to store all information (reminder name, data, time, etc)
        EventInfo eventInfo = new EventInfo();
        // access either Date or Location Fragment (depending on which is visible)  
        // FIXME: access the fragments and get the data
        // let the activity know to display the new reminder
        mEventHandler.handleEvent(eventInfo);
   }
```

1. Question: I started off using only 1 MainActivity with all elements and a ViewFlipper. Then I read that fragments are better to eventually adjust to tablets better. Is this the right way to lay this out?
2. Question: I know how to get the data from *EditNameFragment.java*. But how do I get the data that the user entered from *EditDataFragment* or *EditLocationFragment*? 
   Do I need an instance of those two Fragments in the MainActivity to access their Views? Or do I need another callback like I did with EventHandler? If yes, would the rule be to have a callback for each fragment?

I guess I'm struggling a bit with the communication flow between those components. And I know fragment to fragment communication isn't a good design

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Fragments are self-contained, modular components that would make sense if presented by themselves independently of the other. The canonical example is a list of newspaper articles and the display for an article...both could be presented either independently or separately and it would make sense. In your case, I think having multiple fragments is probably unnecessary because they do not make sense independently of the other (or you would end up with a half-defined event). It seems as if you have one fragment to edit the date and one fragment to edit the name, but conceptually, the two fragments really edit one "object," which is the event. Thus, this should probably be done within one fragment with a ViewFlipper.
2. Have you seen this?

http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html

You need instances of all three fragments in the main activity, and you need to define interfaces for each fragment and implement them in the main activity.

Comment: yes, that makes sense. So I made the right decision first to use only 1 activity and a ViewFlipper. At least I know now for the next time that I need a callback interface for each fragment. Thanks!